# Read fixed width file into an array

Tags: arrays, awk

I am hoping to read the following input into an array via a function using awk FIELDWIDTHS="9 1 2".  I would like the index to be $1.  I am new to Linux and awk and have very little scripting experience so I apologize in advance for offending anyone with such a low level question.  I am hoping to put this into a function where I can define MyArray[ index ]=$2 or MyArray[ index ]=$3 so that I can call the values at a later time.....

```
# input-data.txt
#
# pos(1,9) =$1
# pos(10,1)=$2
# pos(11,2)=$3
#
123456789A01
789123456A02
349751268A04
#
```

Comment: Sorry!, pos(11,2) should equal $3, not $2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a feature of gawk

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Constant-Size.html

To run: `awk -f script.awk file`

**script.awk**

```
#! /bin/awk -f
BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="9 1 2"} 
{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
        myArray[NR][i]=$i
    }
} 
END{
    print "Rec No.--> Field No.--> Value";
    for(i in myArray){
        for( j in myArray[i]){
            print i"-->"j"-->" myArray[i][j]
        }
    }
}
```

**myArray** is an Array of Array, where first index is "Record Number" and second index is "Field Number"

Comment: Thank you Chet! How would this look in script form?

Comment: Chet, not sure this gives me what i want? How would i put this into a function so that i could call MyArray[ index ] = $2

Comment: since there are many records, we cannot hold the record in single dimension, else old array data will be erased on each record run

Comment: Thank you Chet! Seeing this spelled out makes things easier for me to read.....I really appreciate the help!